# Drawing a circle using tkinter without create_oval

Tags: python, tkinter, geometry

On a recent assignment I was tasked with drawing a filled circle in tkinter using the center coordinates and radius as parameters. For any circle I know that radius**2 = (x-centerx)**2 + (y-centery)**2. With this I could throw together:

```
def circle(img, color, radius, center):
x0, y0 = center
for i in range (radius):
    for x in range (x0-i, x0+i):
        for y in range (y0-i, y0+i):
            if (x-x0)**2 + (y-y0)**2 == i**2:
                img.put(color, (x,y))
```

However this only resulted in some dotted outlines of a filled circle, probably due to all points being integers. So then I messed around a bit with the boundaries of the `if` statement and noticed something strange. For:

```
def circle(img, color, radius, center):
x0, y0 = center
for i in range (radius):
    for x in range (x0-i, x0+i):
        for y in range (y0-i, y0+i):
            if i**2 - a <= (x-x0)**2 + (y-y0)**2 <= i**2 + a:
                img.put(color, (x,y))
```

The larger I made `a` the more accurate the circle becomes. How does this work? Since I use `i**2` as a boundary for `x,y` shouldn't increasing `a` lead to larger values of `x,y` being  accepted, making the circle more square?

Answer (score 0):

For filled circle consider filling line-by-line (circle layers are not well-defined for integer coordinates)

```
def circle(img, color, radius, center):
    x0, y0 = center
    for y in range (y0 - radius, y0 + radius + 1):
       wdt = int((radius*radius - y * y)**0.5)
       for x in range (x0-wdt, x0+wdt+1):
            img.put(color, (x,y))
```

Concerning "How does this work?"

```
if i**2 - a <= (x-x0)**2 + (y-y0)**2 <= i**2 + a:
```

here you mark pixels that lie in the ring with inner radius `sqrt(i**2 - a)` and outer radius `i`. Right bound `i**2 + a` has a litle sense because x and y ranges ar limited by `i`. Larger `a` value gives wider ring, so more pixels are marked. In the first code you mark only some pixels that fit to exact equation (like Pythagorean triplets)

Also note that there are special algorithms to draw continuous circumferences like Breseham's algorithm and midpoint algorithm.

Comment: This is a much more elegant solution to the problem but I'm still wondering why increasing `a` leads to an increasingly accurate circle. Since the original equation is derived from pythagoras formula I thought that a greater `i**2` must imply greater `x,y`. My code works for the assignment I just don't know why.

Comment: @TripleEmu I added some explanation

Comment: Is my answer still unclear?